# Why does Instant display different values when printed after eachother?

Tags: java, date, time, java-time

Why does the following code return two different `Instant` values when printed out?

```
Timestamp currentTime = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());

System.out.println(currentTime.toInstant());
System.out.println(Instant.now());
```

When printing out the above two lines at the same time, it will give me:

> 2018-01-10T12:22:46.168Z
>
> 2018-01-10T12:22:46.236Z

Why aren't the printed outputs the same, even though they are called at the same time?

Comment: because time passes...

Comment: Well, it's not called on the exact same time. Isn't it?

Comment: [*Time keeps on slippin', slippin', slippin'… Into the future*](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/stevemillerband/flylikeaneagle.html) — Steve Miller Band

Comment: By the way, no need to mix the modern java.time class `Instant` with the troublesome clumsy hack of a class that is `java.sql.Timestamp`. All date-time classes outside the java.time classes are now legacy and should be avoided. `myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myInstant )` and `myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class )`

Comment: *"even though they are called at the same time?"* - Why do you even think that? There is no logic in that sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you call an API like `System.currentTimeMillis()`, `Instant.now()` and so on, it takes the exact value of when you call it.

The time passes at each instruction. Your processor, driven by the Java Virtual Machine, executes code, one instruction after one, and it takes some time.

Nothing is instantaneous in computer science, and you just found that out.

Answer (score 3):

Each call to `Instant.now()` returns a new `Instant` instance, containing a different time, since time passes between the two calls.

If you use the same instance you'll see the same output:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
Timestamp currentTime = Timestamp.from(now);
System.out.println(currentTime.toInstant());
System.out.println(now);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Instant.now()` makes a call into your opearting system, which in turn reads the hardware clock to obtain the current time. These operations take time, and often longer time than one would expect. 68 milliseconds (the difference between your two times) doesn’t sound unreasonable.

BTW, Basil Bourque is correct in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187710/why-does-instant-display-different-values-when-printed-after-eachother#comment83381501_48187710), when you can use the modern `Instant` class, there’s no reason why you should use the outmoded `Timestamp` too.